# Setting size of hint window (THintWindow) in Delphi/Lazarus

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus, hint

I am trying to make a custom hint in Lazarus. So far I have dynamically loaded the text in the hint, and customized the font face, font size, and font color. I would like to limit the width of the hint window. Any ideas? Here is my code.

```
type
  TExHint = class(THintWindow)
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;

...

constructor TExHint.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  with Canvas.Font do
  begin
    Name  := 'Hanuman';
    Size  := Size + 3;
  end;
  //Canvas.Width := ;
end;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Override the `CalcHintRect` function. The rectangle returned as a result of that function will be the hint size.

Comment: Sorry, novice follow-up. Can you provide the code so I know how and where to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only Lazarus source and notepad now, but I'll try to explain you how the [`THintWindow`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/forms/thintwindow.html) is used since it's the most important to understand:

- If you assign your class name to the [`HintWindowClass`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/forms/hintwindowclass.html) global variable, then you let's say *register* your hint window class for global usage by the application. Then every time the application will going to show hint, it will use your hint window class and call your overriden functions along with the functions from the base [`THintWindow`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/forms/thintwindow.html) class you didn't override. Here is how to *register* your hint window class for use in a scope of the application:

```
HintWindowClass := TExHint;
```

- For getting the hint window size the application calls the [`CalcHintRect`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/forms/thintwindow.calchintrect.html) function whenever the hint is going to be shown. To adjust the hint window size by your own you need to override this function and
  as result return the bounds rectangle you want to have. If you wouldn't override it, the [`CalcHintRect`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/forms/thintwindow.calchintrect.html) function from the base class (from the [`THintWindow`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/forms/thintwindow.html) class) would be used, so you should override it:

```
type
  TExHint = class(THintWindow)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    function CalcHintRect(MaxWidth: Integer; const AHint: String;
      AData: Pointer): TRect; override;
  end;

constructor TExHint.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  with Canvas.Font do
  begin
    Name := 'Hanuman';
    Size := Size + 3;
  end;
end;

function TExHint.CalcHintRect(MaxWidth: Integer; const AHint: String;
  AData: Pointer): TRect;
begin
  // here you need to return bounds rectangle for the hint
  Result := Rect(0, 0, SomeWidth, SomeHeight);
end;
```

Comment: First of all, I really appreciate you taking the time to explain how it works. I am getting compiling error. It says "Error: Identifier not found "TCustomData"". Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I took that from Delphi online reference by mistake. If you take a look at the [`CalcHintRect`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/forms/thintwindow.calchintrect.html) reference or how this function is declared in `forms.pp`unit (better there), you will see the correct prototype. Look at the update ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Now getting error at `Result := Rect(0, 0, 300, 300);`. The error says it is expecting ")", but it is getting a ",".

Comment: I can't see anything wrong on that line; nothing what might cause the error you've described. If the compiler expects `)` but found something else (as you say `,`) then remove the extra `,` before `)`. The line of code from your last comment is correct.

Comment: On the line giving the error it is exactly as I put in the previous comment.

Comment: @preah - Try 'Result := classes.Rect(..'

Comment: Well, you've forced me to start Lazarus (my almost damaged harddrive survived this yet), but there's nothing wrong on this. I've posted you here the full unit source code which IS compilable. @Sertac, you meant `classesh.Rect` don't you :-?

Comment: Great! Thanks much TLama and Sertac. There needs to be a better way to give thumbs up then just a check mark ;). Just as an additional question...is there an easy way to only set the width, and keep the height as it was?

Comment: @Preah - Call the inherited method first: `Result:=inherited CalcHintRect(MaxWidth,Hint,AData);`, then change Result.Left, Result.Right as you wish.

Comment: @Sertac, good point, I'll include it to my post with excuse :-)

Comment: @TLama - Maybe call the inherited method with only specifying MaxWidth is better?

Comment: Setting `Result.right` and `Result.bottom` are in effect doing the same thing as TLama's solution. I want the height automatically set, but the width I set.

Comment: @Sertac, specifying the MaxWidth in this manner `Result:=inherited CalcHintRect(300,Hint,AData);` indeed makes the hint only 300 px wide, but the height is the entire height of the screen.

Comment: No if the `Hint` parameter is different from `''`. In that case the height is being calculated to fit the `Hint` text. If you would pass the `''`, then you would get (almost) the height of the screen. For you (if you say *the width I set*) will be enough to calculate the rectangle by yourself without `inherited` call.

Comment: @TLama, Exactly what I found. I was able put the variable for the text I am loading into `AHint` parameter so it sizes the height correctly, but it actually loads the text in another part of the program. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override CreateParams and set the width to whatever you like.

```
procedure TExHint.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.Width := X; 
end;
```

I haven't tested this but it should work.

Comment: Where do I place and call this procedure?